# JSONKit returning unwanted NSCFString rather than NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, jsonkit, nscfstring

I've been pulling my hair out tried to figure out whats wrong here, for some reason `JSONKit` isn't giving me the dictionary I need so I can reference particular key/value pairs within the plist.

Instead its displaying as a `NSCFString` which obviously doesn't conform to methods like  `ObjectForKey:`. I've scoured around for solutions; telling me to disable ARC, restart/reinstall xcode, and a variety of different implementations but no budging. Worse yet, I have effectively the same code block in another project with the same function and it works seamlessly.

```
NSError * error = NULL;
NSData * plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:plistData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL error:&error];
NSString * jsonString = [plist JSONStringWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionPretty error:&error];
NSDictionary * returnDictionary = [jsonString objectFromJSONString];
for(id elem in returnDictionary)
{
    for(id elements in elem)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",elements);
    }
}
```

The error given:

```
-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1815750
```

The plist in question:

```
<dict>
    <key>20003</key>
    <dict>
        <key>type</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Home Name</string>
        <key>font</key>
        <string>Courier</string>
        <key>size</key>
        <string>22</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>FFFFFFFF</string>
    </dict>
    <key>20001</key>
    <dict>
        <key>type</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>heyhey</string>
        <key>font</key>
        <string>XXX</string>
        <key>size</key>
        <string>11</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>FFFF0000</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What do you get when you `NSLog()` `plist`, `jsonString`, `returnDictionary` and `elem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not JSONKit not returning NSDictionary.

Problem is that when you enumerate through a NSDictionary, you get the "key", not the "value".

So, for the following codes:

```
for(id elem in returnDictionary)
{
    for(id elements in elem)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",elements);
    }
}
```

The type of elem in the outer loop is the "key" for each entry in the dictionary. (Which, from your plist, *is* a string)

Change it to

```
for(id elem in returnDictionary)
{
    id val = returnDictionary[ elem ];
    for(id elements in val)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",elements);
    }
}
```

See if that helps

Comment: Alternately: for (id elem in [returnDictionary allValues]) for the outer loop